# Pipe para modificar (en la vista) el nombre del archivo a descargar desde el servidor? (base de datos en mongoose)

Tags: angular, mongoose

Buen día a todas/todos,

Tengo una base de documentos en mongoose (portafolio) con una colección (proyectos), donde cada proyecto tiene un array de subdocumentos (image). En este momento trabajo en la descarga de archivos que, al ejecutarse muestra el nombre del archivo a descargar en el formato "Ugm5WFhL61epB_hOnDFA1kGa.csv", por ejemplo, (lo que está bien, pues es el nombre del archivo en la base de datos), pero lo que necesito hacer (y aquí el desafío) es que en la vista del usuario, el nombre del fichero a descargar aparezca con su nombre original: "Ultimos_cambios.csv". Revisando alternativas he visto que las "pipes" en Angular, modifican la vista en el lado del usuario, entonces, si esto es así, la que necesito es construir una "pipe personalizada"... el problema mayor es que no se cómo lo debería hacer. Agradezco las ayudas y pistas que me puedan brindar.

Gracias.

Mi modelo de datos:

```
 'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var ImgSchema = Schema({
    FileId: Schema.ObjectId,
    NameDB: String,
    OrigName: String
});

var ProjectSchema = Schema({
    name:String,
    description:String,
    category: String,
    year: Number,
    langs:String,
    image: [ImgSchema]
    //image:[{ img: String }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

En la vista:

```
<ul>
   <section>

        <li *ngFor="let project of projects" class='proyectList'>
            <!-- Si tengo, al menos un archivo en el array de imagenes... -->
            <div *ngIf="project.image.length > 0; else ImgOut" class="infoProyect">
                 <div class="elementList" col-lg>
                    <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
                    <p>{{project.category}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pero si el array de imagenes está vacío... muestro el proyecto con routerLink a editar-->
            <ng-template #ImgOut class="infoProyect">

                <a [routerLink]="[ '/editar-proyecto', project._id ]">
                    <div class="elementList infoProyect" col-lg>
                        <h3>{{project.name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{project.category}}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </ng-template>
            <!-- Muestro los archivos/imagenes para cada proyecto -->
            <div class='listFiles'>

                <div class='img' *ngFor="let img of project.image">

                  <!-- Paso la ruta, el método y el nombre del archivo... necesito -->
                  <!-- que sea el nombre que le asigna mongoose pues este es único -->
                  <!-- Si es un archivo de imagen, lo va a abrir en una pestaña nueva... -->
                  <!-- Si es un 'excel'o algún otro formato va a intentar guardarlo y en la -->
                  <!-- ventana del explorer de windows mostrará 'img.NameDB' en 'guardar como' -->
                  <!-- ***ES AQUI donde necesito dos cosas***: **a )** que siempre se abra la opción para -->
                  <!-- abrir o guardar. **b)** que el nombre que se muestre al usuario corresponda al nombre original del archivo en la base (propiedad: ***img.Origname***)-->
                  <! aquí es donde ***pienso se podría usar una pipe personalizada*** para que, sin cambiar la referencia a 'img.NameDB', la vista del usuario muestre ***img.Origname***)-->
                   <a href="{{url + 'get-image/' + img.NameDB}}" target="_blank">
                      <h4 class="imgnameorig">"{{img.OrigName}}"</h4>
                      <img src="{{url + 'get-image/' + img.NameDB}}" style="width:120px" *ngIf="project.image" />

                    </a>
                    <!-- cada archivo/imagen posee dos botones (editar y eliminar)
                    <div class="ButtonsImg">
                        <!-- 'confirm' es el método que uso en caso de hacer click en 'eliminar' -->
                        <!-- lo inicializo en 'false' -->
                        <p *ngIf="confirm == false">
                            <a [routerLink]="[ '/editar-proyecto', project._id ]" class="button-edit">Editar</a>
                            <!-- cambio el valor de 'confirm' a 'true' y le paso el Id del archivo/imagen -->
                            <a (click)="setConfirm(true);setSebas(img._id)" class="button-delete">Eliminar</a>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="confirm">
                        <!-- Para 'confirm == true' y el Id del archivo/imagen en el array -->
                        <!-- resulta igual al que pasé en 'setSebas(img._id)'... --> 
                        <p *ngIf="confirm == true && sebas == img._id">
                            <span class="confirm">¿Seguro(a) de eliminar este archivo?</span>
                            <a (click)="setConfirm(false)" class="button-edit">cancelar</a>
                            <a (click)="deleteFile(project._id, img._id); setConfirm(false)" class="button-delete">Eliminar</a>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>

                <!--</a>-->

            </div>

            <div class='elementList flexText'>

                <hr>

            </div>

        </li>

    </section>

</ul>
```

Esto es estimados, no se si necesito subir más código para ilustrar mejor lo que necesito pero, en caso de ser así lo puedo agregar.

Comment: Si se puede hacer un pipe personalizado, te copio un enlace a un ejemplo simple 
[Enlace](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=20&codigo=20&inicio=0)

Comment: Gracias Cristian, sí, creo que esto es lo que necesito, voy a probar y luego cuento cómo me ha ido

Comment: Buenisimo, si lo pudiste resolver, no dudes en subirla para verla.